# PhD university ranking when going for post doc/ jobs

Tags: phd, ranking

I have completed my bachelors and masters in engineering from a top UK uni and I am currently working towards my PhD at a low ranked uni (50th in the UK) mainly because it was one of the very few project in my field and with partial funding for non-EU students. My question is how negatively will the ranking of my new university affect me when applying for research jobs / post docs in the future?